# RPi can't access files stored on USB-drive from CLI

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, terminal

I've got USB drive (SD-card reader to be exact) connected to the RPi. 
What I want is to access it's files while in console mode/CLI.

The problem is that **RPi doesn't see files stored on SD card - not until I run GUI by `startx` command**.

- When I go to `/media/my-usb` in CLI and hit `ls` command it
  doesn't list any files.
- When in run file manager in graphic
  interface mode, the files are listed as they should.

The funny thing is that the files are also visible from console launched in graphic interface mode. But as soon as I log off to console mode, they become unreachable again.

`my-usb` folder has 777 permissions

What do I need to do so the **files stored on USB would be accessible in CLI**?

**EDIT:**

- `lsusb` command is listing my device
- `/my-usb` folder is visible by `ls` command under `/media`
- I can also do `cd /media/my-usb` and it enters the folder, but it doesn't see any files inside.

Comment: the drive might not be mounting to `/media/my-usb` Do you see it when you use `lsusb`?

Comment: Yes, it's listed when I use lsusb. It's also listed when I use `ls` while in /media folder. It just doesn't see it's contents.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the file browser or DE that automounts this.  Have a look at `mount | grep media` before and after you start the GUI.

Comment: @goldilocks - You were right. There was an issue with mounting the device. As it turns out GUI seems to have much better way of auto-mounting USB -it works automatically anytime I plug something in, not only if it's plugged in on booting. I think may have to stick with GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `usbmount`.
It's a very good solution, and you can configure it very easily.

`sudo apt-get install usbmount`

Now put in your USB device and you should see it in `/media/usb`.

If not open the usbmount config file: `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arrange automounting outside of the GUI, try creating a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/my.rules` with a line like this:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sda1", RUN+="mount /dev/sda1 /media/my-usb"
```

This presumes the SD card device appears as `/dev/sda`, which it most likely will *if* there's no other drives attached.  I believe you'll have to reboot to make this work.